# How do you determine the Consumers for a given Content Type?

Tags: content-type, powershell

Is there a quick powershell script to find out all the consumers who are consuming a given content type? If yes, how do you do this with powershell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought I had to do this at one point, wrote some code, but never ran it. Here's what I came up with, and you may be able to modify it to your needs.

It finds all the `SPContentTypeUsage`'s for a given content type. In my example, I'm going out and deleting all list items that are of my content type.

```
SPContentType ct = site.RootWeb.ContentTypes["CustomContentType"];

IList<SPContentTypeUsage> usages = SPContentTypeUsage.GetUsages(ct);

foreach (SPContentTypeUsage usage in usages)
{

    if (usage.IsUrlToList)
    {
        SPList list = web.GetList(usage.Url);
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = string.Concat(
                        "<Where><Eq>",
                            "<FieldRef Name='ContentType'/>",
                            string.Format("<Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>", ct.Name),
                        "</Eq></Where>");
        SPListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(query);
        for (int i = 0; i < listItems.Count; i++)
        {
            listItems[i].Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

You wanted powershell. This might get you what you want. Credit goes to Laurie

```
$site = Get-SPSite("your-site-url");
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
   $ctype = $web.ContentTypes["Your Content Type"]
   $usages = [Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPContentTypeUsage]::GetUsages($ctype)
   foreach ($usage in $usages) {
      Write-Host $usage.Url
   }
}
```

[**SOURCE**](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14566/how-to-find-all-documents-of-a-certain-content-type)

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell

1. Find the usages of the content type.

   $w = Get-SPWeb "http://yout/web/url"
   $ct = $w.ContentTypes | Where { $_.ID -eq "[content type id]" }
   [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeUsage]::GetUsages($ct);
2. Go to those places and see the items that are referencing the content type