# Find out where the content type is still in use

Tags: powershell, content-type

I have deleted the content types from the libraries/lists using powershell, but now when I go to delete them at the site level it tells me the content type(s) is still in use. I have checked the Recycle bins of the subsites if there are still items which might be using any of the content type(s), but there is nothing there. Any idea where else I should be looking for the content types?
Or where are they still being used?

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://intprod.local/sites/regions/ap/"
Write-Host $web.Title -ForegroundColor Yellow
foreach($ctype in $web.ContentTypes)
{
        if($ctype.Name -eq "Advertisement")
        {
            Write-Host "CT to be deleted: " $ctype.Name -ForegroundColor Red
            $ctype.Delete()
        }
 }
```

Comment: Probably items using the content type. Have you seen http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/14576/627 ?

Comment: According to powershell it is not being used in any items, and I have deleted them from the libraries. If they were in use in libraries I would not have been able to delete them there.

Comment: There is 2 stages of recycle bins, you should check the site collection administrator recycle bin and remove the items from there to. As long as they remain there, they still "exists".