# How to retrieve all list/library which uses custom content type in a site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type, custom-list, sql, sql-query

How to retrieve all list/library which uses custom content type or a custom column in a site collection?

It would be really helpful if you post your answers in C# code or SQL query.
Please let me know if you have any clarification on the question.
Thanks

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @teylyn, Is something wrong with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint API has class and function [SPContentTypeUsage.GetUsages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttypeusage.getusages.aspx) that returns all content type usages in site collection. Is MSDN article there is an C# sample too.

Also look at the accepted answer in this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14566/how-to-find-all-documents-of-a-certain-content-type) . The answer is in PowerShell.