# Identify unused Content Types SharePoint 2013

Tags: powershell, content-type

We are using SharePoint 2013 and there is multiple content types are created. Some of them are currently in use with multiple list and document libraries but now I want to identify un-used content type and remove them. Can anyone suggest how can I do this or Is there any PowerShell script available to achieve this.

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: surely you can find the usage of the content type. did you have a look this stackexchange https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14566/how-to-find-all-documents-of-a-certain-content-type/14576#14576

Answer (score 0):

```
$myContentType = "ContentType Name" 
$myWebApp = "WebApplication URL"  

 if(!(Get-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue))
{ 
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
}

$results = @()  

$sites = Get-SPSite –Limit All –WebApplication $myWebApp  
try 
{  
    foreach($site in $sites) 
      {  
        Write-Host "Looking in site– " $site.Url  
        foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
         {  
            Write-Host $web.Url  
            foreach($list in $web.lists)
            {  
                foreach($ctype in $list.ContentTypes | ? { $_.Name –eq $myContentType})
                {  
                    foreach($item in $list.Items | ? { $_.ContentType.Name –eq $myContentType })
                    {  
                        $RowDetails = @{  
                            "List" = $list.Title  
                            "ListURL" = $list.DefaultView.Url  
                            "ContentType" = $item.ContentType.Name  
                            "Site" = $site.Url  
                            "Web" = $web.Url  
                         }  
                     $results += New-Object PSObject –Property $RowDetails  
                     break  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
            $web.Dispose()  
        }  
        $site.Dispose()  
    }  
} 

catch  
{  
    $e = $_.Exception  
    $line = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber  
    $msg = $e.Message  
    Write-Host –ForegroundColor Red "Caught Exception: $e at $line"  
    Write-Host $msg  
    Write-Host "Something went wrong"
}  

$results | Export-CSV –Path C:\Users\sp_admin_ps\Documents\sachin\ContentTypeUsageReport.csv –NoTypeInformation  
Write-Host " ***** Completed *****"
```

Comment: I have prepared PowerShell  script for that and it is working fine